# Shortcode if statement

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to print another shortcode when the posts count is 0
any code I add to this code return a fatal error

```
add_shortcode('reviews_total', 'reviews_total_func');

function reviews_total_func()
{ 

    global $post;
    $args = array(
                 'posts_per_page'   => -1,
                 'post_type' => 'testimonial',
                 'meta_key' => '_wpcf_belongs_' . $post->post_type . '_id', 
                'meta_value' => $post->ID,
    );

    $child_posts = get_posts($args);
    return count($child_posts);
}
```

I need to view another shortcode if count($child_posts) = 0

Comment: are those random `<br>` typos?

Comment: no I just typed it here so not to view as one line

Comment: Do you want to execute another shortcode?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the sole purpose of this shortcode is to output the number of posts, why not check for that prior to returning the value?

Example:

```
add_shortcode('reviews_total', 'reviews_total_func');

function reviews_total_func()
{ 

    global $post;
    $args = array(
                 'posts_per_page'   => -1,
                 'post_type' => 'testimonial',
                 'meta_key' => '_wpcf_belongs_' . $post->post_type . '_id', 
                'meta_value' => $post->ID,
    );

    $child_posts = get_posts($args);

    if(count($child_posts) > 0)
         return count($child_posts);
    else
         return "Your custom, alternate zero-posts text";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Execute another shortcode with the function `do_shortcode`

```
add_shortcode('reviews_total', 'reviews_total_func');

function reviews_total_func() { 
    global $post;
    $args = array(
                 'posts_per_page'   => -1,
                 'post_type' => 'testimonial',
                 'meta_key' => '_wpcf_belongs_' . $post->post_type . '_id', 
                'meta_value' => $post->ID,
    );

    $child_posts = get_posts($args);

    if(count($child_posts) > 0)
        return count($child_posts);

    return do_shortcode( '[my-short-code]' );
}
```